# Possible to apply Filter Views on a SharePoint document library when attaching documents in Outlook?

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, attachments, sharepoint-library, sharepoint-list-filter

I have a document library in SharePoint with various Filter Views created to help users find the documents they might be seeking.  This works well if the user accesses the library via the native SharePoint site, or via Microsoft Teams, but when attempting to attach a file from the library in Outlook there are no Filter Views available to help find the document, just a list of all documents sorted by last modified timestamp.

[image: Outlook Attach from SharePoint Library]

Is there any way for the handy Filter Views to be displayed in the Outlook file browser when attaching files like those pictured below available in SharePoint and Teams?

[image: Filter Views in SharePoint]

Comment: I don't think it's possible to choose files from a filtered view of a document library. You can check this post, [ways](https://sharepointmaven.com/7-ways-to-attach-sharepoint-documents-to-an-email/) to attach file to outlook

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, this is impossible to achieve in Outlook.

For Outlook, the Document library is displayed through **Windows File Explorer**, and Teams is displayed through **a connection with SharePoint Online**, so Filter Views can be viewed on Teams.

[image]

[image]

[image]